# Free forum engine with good anti-attack mechanisms

Tags: security, forum

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Forum Software should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/25771/what-forum-software-should-i-use)

I am looking for forum engine (for discussions) with good attack countermeasures built in. Windows (preferrably) or Linux. Free (as beer).

I think about registration flooding and blocking user accounts attacks.

For registration, such engine should have at least:

- captcha
- blocking mulitple registrations from the same IP
- providing login (for logging in) and user name (for displaying the author of the posts)

For logging in:

- no blocking on multiple tries -- instead after X try sending via mail a token, the third piece needed for next login -- without it logging in will be impossible (it would be similar to activation process)

The engine should be designed with two ideas in mind:

- protecting engine against attacks
- 0 penalty for decent users

Thank you in advance for your help and recommendations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPBB has always been good enough for me. You can implement Captcha and you can configure everything else - though the Captcha has been under ridicule.

All of the other PHP-based forums have serious security vulnerabilities that I don't think you'd want.

[For every other feature you might want to know](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Internet_forum_software_%28PHP%29)

Comment: Thank you. I checked the list of features of phpBB before asking and I didn't spot the feature of having doubled nickname (login+username), and this was essential for me.

Comment: With such high standards, have you considered hiring someone to make and / or modify a bulletin board system? freelance.com | odesk.com

Comment: I don't think it is high standard, all is required for implementing this is using an email to login, instead of login :-) It is common sense. I am looking for something ready to use, I am a developer so I could modify given engine myself, but sure hiring is an option as well.

Comment: Just for the record, there is phpBB module (additional) which provides splitting login into (hidden) login and (visible) username.

Comment: Oh, good to know. Yesterday, I remembered that phpBB had modules and such - but I got swept up in work. Good find.